# Net 6.0 set ServiceBusTrigger QueueName and Connection from appsettings instead of local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-functions-isolated

I have a ServiceBusTrigger

`public async Task Run( [ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBus")]`

And I can set QueueName and Connection from **local.settings.json** in "Values" section

```
`"Values": {
    "QueueName": "SbQueueName",    
    "ServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb:...."
  },`
```

How I can set QueueName and Connection from separate custom **appsettings** config
to be able to use custom setting section naming

```
"CustomSectionName": {    
    "QueueName": "SbQueueName",
    "ServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb:...."
  }
```

Comment: Create custom appsetting.json file? a different json file? and you want to add settings there? Or use existing appsettings.json file and add a different section?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a value from a custom-named section in appsettings.json, you'll need to implement a mechanism to access this section and pass it to your Azure Function by [runtime binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd#binding-at-runtime).

It would probably be easier and more straight forward to set them in the root of an appsettings file and give them a custom name, like so:
Code:

```
public async Task Run( [ServiceBusTrigger("%CustomQueueName%", Connection = "CustomServiceBus")]
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
   "CustomQueueName": "SbQueueName",
   "CustomServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb:...."
}
```

As for using a custom appsettings config file, use this line in your Startup.cs:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var services = builder.Services;
        var context = builder.GetContext();

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), false)
            // Custom appsettings
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.Custom.json"), false) // Or whatever name you'd like
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
       ...
       }
```

Comment: Tried the same way but we are getting the following error

The 'Function1' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%queuename%' does not resolve to a value.